# DesktopLauncher is not available when uncheck the android in LibGdx Installation

Tags: libgdx

I couldn't find the DesktopLauncher whenever i'm adding a configuration in my LibGdx project whenever i uncheck the android checkbox on LibGdx set up. But it works whenever check the android checkbox. What am i missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "not available" ? Is the file created ? Is this an issue with your IDE ? What IDE ? Is there desktop in your `gradle.settings` file ? Is it the module that is missing or just the main class ?

Comment: When I uncheck checkbox for android sub projects,then only android folder not present in project destination folder. you can find DesktopLauncher class is desktop folder.

Comment: @Winter, There's no DesktopLauncher available in the main class when i am adding a configuration. I'm using Android Studio

Comment: @ErrolPaleracio where are you adding configuration and what do you mean by main class ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan For desktop sir. There is a field called main class.

Comment: @ErrolPaleracio Have you selected **Use classpath of modle : desktop** in Run Configuration dialog ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan, i actually missed that. My bad. It's already working.

Answer (score 3):

Set **Use classpath of modle : desktop** in Run Configuration dialog then select 
**main class : DesktopLauncher**.